# Combobox in tcl gives error when any item is selected in it

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, bwidget

I'm using tk widget Combobox and whenever I select any item in it it gives

```
invalid command name .top47.not48.fpage2.sw.sf.frame.cf2.frame.c.shell.listb
```

my code looks like this:-

```
ComboBox $mainframe.cf2.frame.c -textvariable variable1 \
        -values Corners -modifycmd "new_values"
```

This is the main combobox that controls all the values of other combobox'es present in it which don't give any error like this.

Comment: That's a most unlikely name for a widget in that error message; it should start with a “`.`”. Is it transcribed exactly?

Comment: Sorry for that actually mainframe is .top47.not48.fpage2.sw.sf.frame

Comment: OK, that's let me improve the formatting on your question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely due to an error in the "new_values" function you have omitted. As a sample to show this:

```
package require BWidget
proc modify {} {.xyzzy something}
ComboBox .c -textvariable v -values Corners -modifycmd modify
pack .c
```

Now when you run this and select an entry from the dropdown you get 'Error: invalid command name ".xyzzy"'. The window you are trying to address is evidently digging into the internal implementation of this BWidgets class as `winfo children .c` shows me that .c.shell.listb exists. However, this is unsafe - the implementation may change from one version to the next and you don't control when the dropdown is created and destroyed. Check for the existence of your target window using `winfo exists $combo.shell.listb` as a minimum. You may want to ensure a compatible version of the BWidgets package too by using `package require -exact BWidget 1.M.N`